# Service fabric upgrade created a error on VSTS build server

Tags: continuous-integration, tdd, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines

We have upgraded our Service Fabric SDK and tools from 2.5.216 to 2.6.210.

Now when we run a build on the VSTS hosted agent, the build fails during the acceptance test stage, which runs specflow acceptance tests via vstest.exe.

The error is:

Could not load type 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.IReliableConcurrentQueue`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.","exceptionType":"System.TypeLoadException"

The tests work locally (with Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools 2.6.210 (VS2015) installed) using the same vstest.exe command.

Having looked at the specification of the hosted agent (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted)
we've noted that the versions installed on the agent are Service Fabric 5.4.164.9494 / Service Fabric SDK 2.4.164, and suspect these
need to be updated.

**Longer version of the error**

> 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0331094Z Failed   I can make a request to change
>   the allocation of a game type 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0331094Z
>
> ### [error]Error Message: 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]   System.Exception : Non matching response code: InternalServerError -
>
> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Could not load
>   type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.IReliableConcurrentQueue`1'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.","exceptionType":"System.TypeLoadException","stackTrace":"
>   at Infrastructure.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHelper.ThrowIfUnhandled()
>   in
>   d:\\a\\1\\s\\Infrastructure\\Infrastructure.ExceptionHandling\\ExceptionHelper.cs:line
>   45\r\n   at
>   xwx.WebApi.Controllers.gameTypesController.<UpdategameType>d__8.MoveNext()
>   in
>   d:\\a\\1\\s\\Orchestration\\xwx\\xwx.WebApi\\Controllers\\gameTypesController.cs:line
>   142\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]   at
>   Infrastructure.TestHelpers.AcceptanceTests.ResponseHelper.AssertResponseHadExpectedStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.TestHelpers\AcceptanceTests\ResponseHelper.cs:line
>   25 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.ResponseSteps.ThenIShouldReceiveAHttpStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\ResponseSteps.cs:line
>   12 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ICanMakeARequestToChangeTheAllocationOfAgameType()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\ChangeAllocation.feature:line
>   43Error Message: 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]
>   System.Exception : Non matching response code: NoContent - 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   Infrastructure.TestHelpers.AcceptanceTests.ResponseHelper.AssertResponseHadExpectedStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.TestHelpers\AcceptanceTests\ResponseHelper.cs:line
>   25 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.gameTypesSteps.WhenTheChangeHasCompleted()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\gameTypesSteps.cs:line
>   167 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0351049Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:00.0361050Z  2017-06-20T15:11:00.0361050Z Failed   I
>   can increase the allocation 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0361050Z 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5390956Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ICanIncreaseTheAllocation()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\ChangeAllocation.feature:line
>   52Error Message: 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]
>   System.Exception : Non matching response code: NoContent - 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   Infrastructure.TestHelpers.AcceptanceTests.ResponseHelper.AssertResponseHadExpectedStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.TestHelpers\AcceptanceTests\ResponseHelper.cs:line
>   25 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.gameTypesSteps.WhenTheChangeHasCompleted()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\gameTypesSteps.cs:line
>   167 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z Failed   If I try to reduce the
>   allocation below the number of games available I can only reduce the
>   allocation to the total available 2017-06-20T15:11:01.5400956Z 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0426998Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.IfITryToReduceTheAllocationBelowTheNumberOfgamesAvailableICanOnlyReduceTheAllocationToTheTotalAvailable()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\ChangeAllocation.feature:line
>   70Error Message: 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0426998Z ##[error]
>   System.Exception : Non matching response code: NoContent - 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0426998Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0426998Z ##[error]   at
>   Infrastructure.TestHelpers.AcceptanceTests.ResponseHelper.AssertResponseHadExpectedStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.TestHelpers\AcceptanceTests\ResponseHelper.cs:line
>   25 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.gameTypesSteps.WhenTheChangeHasCompleted()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\gameTypesSteps.cs:line
>   167 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ICanReduceTheAllocationByTheNumberOfgamesStillAvailable()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\ChangeAllocation.feature:line
>   61Error Message: 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]
>   System.Exception : Non matching response code: NoContent - 
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]Stack Trace:
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   Infrastructure.TestHelpers.AcceptanceTests.ResponseHelper.AssertResponseHadExpectedStatusCode(Int32
>   expectedStatusCode) in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.TestHelpers\AcceptanceTests\ResponseHelper.cs:line
>   25 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.gameTypesSteps.WhenTheChangeHasCompleted()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Tests\Orchestration\xwx\xwx.AcceptanceTests\gameTypes\gameTypesSteps.cs:line
>   167 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding
>   binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments,
>   ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch
>   match, Object[] arguments) 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance
>   stepInstance) 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z ##[error]   at
>   xwx.AcceptanceTests.gameTypes.ChangeAllocation3532Feature.ScenarioCleanup()
>   2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z Failed   I can reduce the allocation by
>   the number of games still available 2017-06-20T15:11:03.0437002Z

Comment: Andreas we would love to get your feedback on this issue.

Comment: The VS2017 Hosted agent has a compatible SDK/Runtime installed. The other option is to bring your own agent.

Comment: What's the detail build log? Could you share a simple sample that can reproduce this issue on the OneDrive?

Comment: ok updated the post. Added a detailed log.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're specifying platform target x64 on the build server, check your project build configuration to see if Release is set to platform target x64.

Also ensure the build server has the latest Service Fabric SDK installed. It's possible that the problematic build is picking up old assemblies from the GAC.

Here's the error I was getting,

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.IReliableStateManagerReplica2' from assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use [SDK only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#sdk-installation-only) by install [Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services/2.6.210) package. Works fine for me with Hosted agent.

Comment: Don't now how to see that in VSTS it is a cloud based solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755900/how-do-we-see-the-assemblies-installed-on-vsts-build-server

Comment: I would run this as I understand Install-Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services -Version 2.6.210

Comment: This page points the installed components. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted   The installed ones are Service Fabric 5.4.164.9494
Service Fabric SDK 2.4.164

Comment: "You can just use SDK only by install Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services package. Works fine for me with Hosted agent."  How do I this ? As in by packages.config there is the necessary reference. Should I run the exe on the server if so how ?

Comment: Is this the powershel to run ? Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
$down = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url  = 'http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK';
$file = 'MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK.exe';
$down.DownloadFile($url,$file);
$exec = New-Object -com shell.application
$exec.shellexecute($file);

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin Can you share a simple sample that could reproduce that issue (e.g. OneDrive)?

Comment: I was unable to use the hosted agent... Please give more details how you have accomplished this.

Comment: Could you share a simple sample project on the OneDrive? I will verify it.