# How do we see the assemblies installed on VSTS build server

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am getting this error on visual studio online servers. I would like to see why it failed ? How do I see what is installed on visual studio build agent ?

**Error**

> 2017-06-20T15:11:00.0341044Z ##[error]   System.Exception : Non
>   matching response code: InternalServerError - {"message":"An error has
>   occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections.IReliableConcurrentQueue`1'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.","exceptionType":"System.TypeLoadException","stackTrace":"
>   at Infrastructure.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHelper.ThrowIfUnhandled()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.ExceptionHandling\ExceptionHelper.cs:line
>   45\r\n   at
>   xxxx.WebApi.Controllers.yyyyTypesController.d__8.MoveNext()
>   in
>   d:\a\1\s\Orchestration\xxxxGenius\xxxxx.WebApi\Controllers\yyyyTypesController.cs:line
>   142\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at

**Where should I click ?**

[image]

Comment: Could you share a simple sample that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Where is the assembly `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces` coming from? Nuget package? Or is it a reference to an assembly on your hard drive (source control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build is telling you why it failed: It can't find the assembly `Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Interfaces`.

The software loaded on the hosted agent is [well documented](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software). If the hosted agent doesn't have something you need, and you can't install it as a NuGet/NPM package, then you'll have to set up your own agent that has the required software on it.

Comment: thanks after seeing this I have created our own build agent. I guess If you really want to update your apps periodcly you need custom build server.